# How to trigger a function with a button in PHP?

Tags: php, function, curl

I want to trigger a function that i have written with an already existing button.

The button is used for saving data already.

I want to add my code (which is working and tested) to the page and trigger it when the button is clicked along with the previous submit of data.

I have setup the code in php using curl, and i have tested it and it works, however for the life of me, i am unable to connect it to trigger when someone clicks on the button.

The button already has a function to submit, i want to add this to it as well.

```
$whmcsUrl = "https://example.com/billing/";

$username = "APIUSER";
$password = "APIPASS";

$postfields = array(
    'action' => 'SendEmail',
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'messagename' => 'Verification - Card',
    'id' => $_POST["clientid"];,
            'responsetype' => 'json',
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/billing/includes/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

// Decode response
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);

// Dump array structure for inspection
var_dump($jsonData);
```

This is my main code, i want to add it to a button

the code for button is here

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verification" id="btnSubmitNewCard" type="submit" name="submit" value="{$LANG.clientareasavechanges}" />
```

Comment: The `onclick` attribute should be a function call, like `onclick="verification()"`

Comment: The button submits the form. You just need to put the PHP code into the script that processes the form.

Comment: @Barmar i tried, it didnt work.

Comment: @Barmar how about i put the code in a seprate file and somehow trigger it using the submit button, will that work?

Comment: The `verification()` function can use AJAX to call this code.

Comment: @Barmar any tip on how to set it?

Comment: Read a tutorial on AJAX, I'm not going to try to teach you here.